# MapAnnotation, how can we decide the zIndex of an Annotation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

when using the MapKit.Map to display multiple Annotation overlapping, everything works properly whether you use `MapPin`, `MapMarker` or `MapAnnotation`.

The tricky part is to bring an annotation to the front once you `clickOnAnnotation`.
Considering `MapPin`, `MapMarker` or `MapAnnotation` are `MapAnnotationProtocol` Custom Types, which respectively, defined as follow in apple documentation:

```
// Available when SwiftUI is imported with MapKit
@available...
public protocol MapAnnotationProtocol {}

@available...
public struct MapMarker : MapAnnotationProtocol {
    public init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, tint: Color? = nil)
}

// Available when SwiftUI is imported with MapKit
@available...
public struct MapPin : MapAnnotationProtocol {
    public init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, tint: Color? = nil)
}

// Available when SwiftUI is imported with MapKit
@available...
public struct MapAnnotation<Content> : MapAnnotationProtocol where Content : View {
    public init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, anchorPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
}
```

How can we implement a CustomView which also implements this protocol but provides us also with the needed properties which allows us to access the cooler feature of The Map (like zIndex as a start)?

I know we can still use `UIViewRepresentable` but that is not my goal, unless ...

helpfull Links:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map
- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/07/29/using-mapkit-with-swiftui/
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/integrating-mapkit-with-swiftui
- https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/map-with-annotations-in-swiftui

Comment: In SwiftUI, map annotations are simply a view. However, I think the Z index is handled by the system. I am not sure you can control that.

Comment: you may want to look at an alternative to using `zIndex`, such as decluttering, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering  that caters for your overlapping Annotations.

Comment: the cluttering is not the issue, it is to bring the clicked annotation to the front. I would have expected a zIndex to be enough to handle this, but the problem is that map embeds the customAnnotationView (let's say in this case a simple circleShape) inside the mapAnnotation which is a custom type of MapAnnotationProtocol and the only property you can access within the protocol is _annotationData which is not documented at all.
this link: https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/map-with-annotations-in-swiftui helps with adding different annotationTypes but that is it :( .

Comment: here is a link with a sample project for the matter: https://github.com/MohamedAymenHADDAD/MapSU-Prototype

Comment: related apple dev Thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705399

Comment: I updated the repository with another branch : `MapIntrospect`.
As the name indicates I am trying to use Introspect to bring the selectedAnnotationView to the front. You can not actually see the changes but if you use the `Debug view hierarchy` you would notice that the view was properly updated however on the device display there is no noticeable changes.
I have seen also, sometimes, that the view is brought to the front but directly after sent back to its initial position.

Answer (score 2):

After creating a TSI (Technical Support Incident) we got the following:

> We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no
> supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently
> shipping system configurations.

suggestion was submitted to feedback assistant.